# What is the proper plural form of 'apparatus'?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

Dictionary.com claims that the plural of 'apparatus' is 'apparatuses'. Surely that can't be right... isn't it 'apparati'?

Comment: Try it out and see. It certainly comes from a Latin word, but did it bring along its Latin plural form? Many don't.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Should I check its passport into English-land then?

Comment: "Apparatus" has Latin plural "apparatus" (not "apparati"--my Latin teachers would be appalled). English can either accommodate the Latin plural "apparatus" or use the English plural "apparatuses" of the anglicized word. Both are correct.

Comment: Definitely never octopi - the original word is Greek but is octopous; so octopus is always an English word taking an English plural. Antipodes is a Greek plural, but oddly one never sees thee singular, although when people in Europe say that I'm from the antipodes I point out that so are they - I'm from the southern antipous, they're from the northern. An otherwise useful website referred to in this discussion claims that datum is never used in English; an engineer will quickly disabuse you of that misconception; certainly I prefer to treat data as plural but wouldn't say it was wrong to do ot

Comment: Relevant overall discussion: [How do you decline nouns borrowed from languages with several categories for declining nouns (or none at all)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70335/how-do-you-decline-nouns-borrowed-from-languages-with-several-categories-for-dec)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [Latin plural](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apparatus#Noun_2) of the noun *apparatus* is actually *apparatus*. (Sometimes the Latin is spelled singular *apparātus* and plural *apparātūs*; the vowel lengthens in the plural, but that's not usually reflected in the spelling.) This is because it's fourth declension. In the 18th and 19th centuries, when most educated English speakers had studied Latin, *apparatus* was sometimes used as the plural; I believe this usage is quite rare today.

With *status*, *apparatus*, and other Latin nouns of the fourth declension ending in *-us*, the English plural adds an *-es*. The Latin nouns which pluralize by turning an *-us* into an *-i*, like *radius, fungus, alumnus*, are all second declension. For some Latin nouns of the second declension, like *campus*, the Latin plural has been lost, and the English plural adds an *-es*. But *campi* would be correct in Latin, while *apparati* is incorrect in both English and Latin.

You don't actually hear the English plural *apparatuses* that often, because *apparatus* is often treated as a semi-uncountable noun: *one apparatus*, *two pieces of apparatus*. [(See Google Ngrams.)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+apparatus%2Ctwo+apparatuses%2Ctwo+pieces+of+apparatus%2Ctwo+apparatus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20apparatus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20apparatuses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20pieces%20of%20apparatus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20apparatus%3B%2Cc0) I assume this usage developed because people didn't know whether to use *apparatus* or *apparatuses* for the plural, and figured out a way of avoiding the issue altogether.

Comment: In technical and scientific work dealing with this and that ***corpus***, Latin’s third declension plural of ***corpora*** came right along with it. *O tempora, o mores!* (Ciceronian citation because that’s the only other third declension noun I could quickly (*tempus fugit*) think of that people might generally recognize.)

Comment: How does the vowel extension reflect? Also, where can I read about determining which declension a noun is?

Comment: Latin declensions are found by looking at the genitive, given as the second word form in a Latin dictionary, and/or are simply memorized. Long vowels in Latin may be written under a macron, eg. status → statūs, but this is inconsistent usage across time, place, et al. and is often omitted.

Answer (score 10):

What Peter said. If you really have to make a plural of the English word, you could use *apparatus*, which is given as a plural in the OED. But the OED also gives *apparatuses*, which seems a much better bet.

Comment: And to further complicate things, *apparatus* is usually a mass noun, so if you dealing with several pieces of apparatus, according to the OED, all of the following are grammatical: *the apparatuses are ready, the apparatus are ready,* and *the apparatus is ready.* I'd use the last one.

Comment: I think I would too.

Answer (score 9):

As @JohnLawler said, not all Latin words keep their Latin plurals. Consider:

- [virus](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3840/25030)/viruses (not virii, see link)
- fetus/fetuses
- victor/victors
- vector/vectors
- minus/minuses
- onus/onuses
- sinus/sinuses
- status/statuses ([yes, statuses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/881/25030))
- stadium/stadiums (Greek word actually but came to English through Latin and (almost) nobody says *stadia*)

And the list goes on. I have no Latin so I don't know how many of these don't keep their plural because of the rule mentioned in @PeterShor's answer but you can see that many Latin words have normal English plurals. In other words, trust the dictionary, it tends to know more than we do.

Comment: "nobody says stadia". Well, [in Dutch they do](http://www.meervoudvan.com/stadium/). Using the same Latin root (although interestingly, the Dutch use 'stadion' - the Greek word - for the sports arena, and 'stadium' for 'era / epoch'.

Comment: @Floris well, yes, OK, in other languages sure. I was talking about English. We say _stadia_ (στάδια) in Greek as well.

Comment: "Nobody says stadia". It's not uncommon in the UK: see, for example, the [UK Parliament](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/all?text=stadia), the [BBC](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stadia+site:bbc.co.uk), the [*Daily Telegraph*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stadia+site:telegraph.co.uk).

Comment: @DavidRicherby well yes, that'swhy I mentioned that nobody says it. I know it exists, it's just very rarely used in normal conversation which is why I said that nobody _says_ it. Some may of course write it but, fair enough, answer edited.

Comment: @terdon I don't think this has anything to do with written versus spoken English. Anyone who writes "stadia" is going to say it, too; if it's true that the word is rarely used in spoken English, it's because people rarely need to talk about more than one stadium, not because people write "stadia" but say "stadiums".

Comment: [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stadiums%2Cstadia&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) suggests *stadiums* only overtook *stadia* around 1980 and both are in use

Answer (score 9):

To write "apparati" is an example of a *hypercorrection*:

> In linguistics or usage, hypercorrection is a non-standard usage that results from the over-application of a perceived rule of grammar or a usage prescription. A speaker or writer who produces a hypercorrection generally believes that the form is correct through misunderstanding of these rules, often combined with a desire to appear formal or educated.

It's the pedant's own-goal, basically. I've made many. Using "whom" as a subject pronoun is a classic.

Some more examples similar to the question are:

- *octopi* instead of *octopuses*
- *scenaria* or *scenarii* instead of *scenarios*
- *penii* instead of *penises*

Although in some cases (see ["octopi" vs "octopuses" on Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=octopuses%2Coctopi&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coctopuses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coctopi%3B%2Cc0)) the hypercorrected form may be common enough to be accepted as standard usage.

In the case of "syllabus", for instance, an [analysis of the Latin](http://languagesoftheworld.info/morphology/the-plural-of-virus-latinate-plurals-reconsidered.html) shows "syllabi" to be a hypercorrection. However [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=syllabus%2C+syllabi%2C+syllabuses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csyllabus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csyllabi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csyllabuses%3B%2Cc0) shows it to be more widely used than the supposedly more correct "syllabuses".

Comment: [Syllabus](http://epectasis.blogspot.jp/2010/07/curious-and-quibbling-history-of_23.html) is an incredibly interesting case. It is neither Latin nor Greek, but a misprint.

Comment: @PeterShor that is interesting. Here's an example of that sort of thing happening in "real time" and even within the same language: The term in geometry for a truncated tapering solid (e.g. a pyramid or cone with the point chopped off) is a [Frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum). Wen I recently used the word in a few Facebook posts, _every single person_ within my (broadly, "college-educated") peer circle who commented had misread it as "Frustrum". Even the one who pondered whether the plural should be "Frustra" rather than "Frustrums". (Or, as I actually wrote, "Frustums".)

Comment: (And, yes, I absolutely charged myself the $25 pretentious-word fee, along with an admission that I had to first look it up myself.)

Answer (score 1):

This singular/plural problem affects many languages that have given loanwords to English. Arabic is a bugbear for non-Arabists. The word Caliph (originally khalifa) has its correct plural as khulafa'. An increasingly common term, hadith (a prophetic tradition) is ahadith, and that confuses because of what looks like an English indefinite article at the beginning. (The middle vowel also lengthens. A Bedouin is worse: it is already an inflected sound plural (the previous two are 'broken') and it is also used in English as a plural. One Bedouin is a badu, nominative Bedouins are Badawun, and the adjective is badawi. A similar form is assassin, which starts as an inflected plural hashshashin. A hashshash is, reputedly, someone who smokes hashish (grass). Hummus comes from a collective plural himmas (and variants),chickpeas. And much more....

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a traditional discussion forum, but a Q&A site where "answers" are expected to address the original post directly. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.