# Is it okay to pluralize the word "status"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Am I using the plural noun *statuses* correctly in the following sentence given that each of them has a distinct status?

"Both the girl and the guy are hiding their social *statuses* from each other."

Should I say *status* instead?

Comment: It's done, and generally accepted, at least in less formal writings.

Comment: Please see a good dictionary.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/877/14666 "What is the plural form of "status"?"

Comment: What about "states"?

Comment: I agree with lux, to me the word "states" sounds more right to pronounce, but it may be wrong. I'd like to hear what an english speaking person thinks about it.

Answer (score 4):

The OED refers to three possible plurals, two of which are now rare.

Status  (rare)

Statuses   (now usual)

Statusses (rare).

> Inflections:   Pl. (rare) status  /ˈsteɪtjuːs/ , (now usu.) statuses 
>   /ˈsteɪtəsɪz/ , (rare) statusses  /ˈsteɪtəsɪz/ .
>
> Etymology:  A borrowing from Latin. Etymon: Latin status.

Comment: Better to include a link to the resource.

Comment: @Kris OED is subscription only

Comment: @Kris [This is the link](http://www.oed.com/) but unless you are a UK Council Tax payer, and your municipal library has given you a log-in, I'm afraid it is subscription-only.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Anglicized plural would indeed be *statuses*, although if you wanted to get fancy I suppose you could use *status*, which is actually the Latin plural (since it's a 4th declension not a 2nd declension noun, in case anyone's interested.... If it were 2nd declension, the plural would be *stati*.)

Comment: Very interesting. When we borrow foreign words, do we necessarily bring down the derivative forms or use English derivations? Btw, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=status  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/status#Etymology_4

Comment: I guess it's a fairly even mix of Latin plurals and derived plurals... (Also i was referring to the noun form of status that is in fact 4th declension, rather than the perfect passive participle-turned-noun which is 2nd).

Answer (score -1):

Here's the sole intelligent reason for having a gender-neutral third personal pronoun meaning indifferently 'he or she", "him or her", "his or her".
Let's adopt for this the made-up word *ig* (declined *ig, ig, igz*) and then say "*each hiding igz social status from the other*". No awkward plural needed!
If there are more than 2 people, we can say "*others*".